# Are there mechanics for god creation through sufficient faith?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, religions-and-deities

My friend told me the story of Orcus cultists who had created a fake religion in order to invade the city only to have the god of that religion become a real god and defend the city against them.

Are there any mechanics to determine how a god is created, or is it left to DM discretion?

Comment: Have you read *Deities and Demigods*?  what counts as created and what do you mean by sufficient faith?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I think the asker means *created* in much the same way that Elan's faith grants a degree of divinity to the previously-not-a-divine-being (and, really, previously-not-even-alive) [Banjo the Clown](http://oots.wikia.com/wiki/Banjo_the_Clown).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sourcebook on this is Deities & Demigods, which officially leaves it up to the DM:

> Gods are immortal beings with power beyond mortal capabilities. You decide where they come from.

However, there is precedent for becoming a deity simply by number of followers. In *Vecna Lives*, Vecna is slain by his lieutenant, only to be reborn centuries later as a deity after a cult grows and begins to worship him. In *Age of Worms*, cultists manage to summon a demon in the shape of a fake god. And in *Ivid the Undying*, a pit fiend becomes a deity by having a dictator install him as the state religion.

The rules for divine rank also suggest that deities with more followers have more power. *Age of Worms* suggests that there's a causative link, with a rank 0 deity who becomes more powerful depending on the number of people who fear his return.

In general, however, creating deities isn't something player characters do a lot, so there aren't any real mechanics on it (aside from divine rank, which you can find in Deities & Demigods or the divine rules in the SRD). The DM is free to decide whether or not deities can be created through sufficient faith in their world.

Comment: The DM is free to decide, but should they decide deities are dependent on worshippers, there *are* mechanics for that in the book you mention.